# Can't define soup.find_all for scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Need help defining the proper HTML code for web scraping.

I have a .csv with 1000+ urls for restaurant menus from the same site and need to add extra columns with information for each restaurant. The problem is that I only need some of the menu. This is a selection of my list of lists:

```
['subdomain', 'name', 'url']
['https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/recoleta/empanadas-delivery?bt=RESTAURANT&page=1', 'Cümen-Cümen Empanadas Palermo', 'https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/cumen-cumen-empanadas-palermo-menu']
['https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/recoleta/empanadas-delivery?bt=RESTAURANT&page=1', 'El Maitén Empanadas - Al horno o fritas', 'https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el-maiten-empanadas-al-horno-o-fritas-menu']
```

So I need to go through every URL looking for:

a) The info in:

```
<span class="new_rating box_split_review_04">4.9</span>
```

So in that example it's rating = 4.9.

b) I also need every menu item with "empanada" in the name. The problem is that some of the menus add extra things such as: Empanadas al horno, Empanadas fritas etc. What I need is the price of every type of empanada:

```
<div class="price">
<span class="discounted-price">$49,99</span>
<span class="has-discount">$62,49</span>
</div>
```

So the output should be something like: (saved as a .CSV)

```
['subdomain', 'name', 'url', 'rating', 'empanada_price']
['https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/recoleta/empanadas-delivery?bt=RESTAURANT&page=1', 'Cümen-Cümen Empanadas Palermo', 'https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/cumen-cumen-empanadas-palermo-menu', '4,9', '$49,99']
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? What problem did you run into? This is not a code writing service. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi Razdi, sorry for not explaining myself well enough. The problem is what I stated in b), a lot of the items in the menu have slightly different names, and I'm not sure how to go about this. Definitely not asking for code writing services, a nudge in the right way would bbe more than satisfying! Thanks :)

Comment: You can try to look for every `div` with `class="content"`. Once there, maybe look for those that have a heading with `class="prdouctName"` and has a value that [contains](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) Empanadas in the [string value](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text). This will give you the target divs sontaining empanadas and then you can look for the corresponding prices.